# Problem in array search

Tags: php, search, arrays

I am trying to find values inside an array. This array always starts with 0.
unfortunately array_search start searching with the array element 1.
So the first element is always overlooked.

How could I "shift" this array to start with 1, or make array-search start with 0? The array comes out of an XML web service, so I can not rally modify the results.

Comment: Maybe you should show your code and how you search because obviously `array_search` works correct But maybe it is not the right function for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manual, it might help you:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

If what you're trying to do is use increase the key by one, you can do:

```
function my_array_search($needle, $haystack, $strict=false) {
     $key = array_search($needle, $haystack, $strict);
     if (is_integer($key)) $key++;
     return $key;
}
my_array_search($xml_service_array);
```

Comment: hmm thanx but  can u explain more because i used Zero but not working . does  array_search() start at the 0 key ?

Comment: sure the index key is Zero , look down at what meagar said as an example

Comment: This example technically will solve your problem, but the resulting key will point 1 past the element you want to find.  You'll still be finding element 0 though.  Thus the key it returns won't actually tell you where to find the data.

Answer (score 14):

`array_search` does *not* start searching at index 1.  Try this example:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('blue', $array);  // $key = 0
?>
```

Whatever the problem is with your code, it's not that it's first element is index 0.

It's more likely that you're use `==` instead of `===` to check the return value.  If array_search returns 0, indicating the first element, the following code will not work:

```
// doesn't work when element 0 is matched!
if (false == array_search(...)) { ... }
```

Instead, you **must** check using `===`, which compares both value and type

```
// works, even when element 0 is matched
if (false === array_search(...)) { ... }
```

Comment: wow thanx buddy that was awesome , i think i find out the  problem .

Comment: At it is said in this big red **warning** box on this site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php   Reading manual pages sometimes really helps!